# Check the page's content after a reload on Jest with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, jestjs, puppeteer, page-refresh, jest-puppeteer

I'm developing a nodejs library similar to live-reload/browser-sync and I'm using **[jest-puppeteer](https://github.com/smooth-code/jest-puppeteer)** for the automated tests.

When I manually test my library, opening the browser and modifying a file, *voilá*, the pages refreshes (through an injected code that runs a `location.reload( true )` when it receives a signal through a websocket).

But when I run the test with Jest, it seems that Puppeteer doesn't get the refresh.

```js
// "reloader" is my library
import reloader from './../src/index';

import * as fs              from 'fs';
import { promisify }        from 'util';

const read  = promisify( fs.readFile )
const write = promisify( fs.writeFile )

test('1. Refresh when file changes', async () => {

    const server  = await reloader( { dir: 'test/01' } );

    await page.goto( 'http://localhost:' + server.port );

    // This test passes
    await expect( page.title()).resolves.toMatch( 'Old title' );

    // Read and modify index.html to generate a refresh 
    const file    = 'test/01/index.html'
    const content = await read( file, 'utf8' );
    await write( file, content.replace( 'Old title', 'New title' ) );

    // Wait the page to refresh
    await page.waitForNavigation( { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' } )

    // This test doesn't pass
    // Still receiving "Old title" 
    await expect( page.title()).resolves.toMatch( 'New title' );

    // Undo the changes
    write( file, content );

});
```

On the last test, instead of receiving the `New title` (that is being written correctly in the `index.html` file), I'm still receiving `Old title`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tests were failing because the last part bellow the comment `\\ Undo the changes` weren't running, and the test file remained with the `New title`.

With the test below, it worked perfectly:

```js
import reloader from './../src/index';

import * as fs              from 'fs';
import { promisify }        from 'util';

const read  = promisify( fs.readFile )
const write = promisify( fs.writeFile )

test('1. Refresh when file change', async () => {

    // If this test failed previously, lets guarantee that
    // everything is correct again before we begin
    const file    = 'test/01/index.html'
    const content = ( await read( file, 'utf8' ) ).replace( 'New title', 'Old title' );
    await write( file, content );

    const server  = await reloader( { dir: 'test/01' } );

    await page.goto( 'http://localhost:' + server.port );

    await expect( page.title()).resolves.toMatch( 'Old title' );

    // Read and modify index.html to generate a refresh 
    await write( file, content.replace( 'Old title', 'New title' ) );

    // Wait the page to refresh
    await page.waitForNavigation( { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' } )

    await expect( page.title()).resolves.toMatch( 'New title' );

    // Undo the changes
    write( file, content );

});
```